# Calendar.getTime() to Date object

Tags: java, android, django, date, calendar

I've an instance of a Calendar setted with UTC time zone, I need to be UTC becouse I've to sync with a server that is UTC.

I need to create a Date object from this Calendar, and I use Calendar.getTime().

But when I try to print out the Date object I see it with a different TimeZone (CEST instead of UTC)

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
cal.setTime(timeMillisecond);
Date d = cal.getTime();
Log.d("TAG", d.toString());
```

EDIT:

When I pass the date object to the server, I get it with CEST timezone instead of UTC time zone.

Comment: A `Date` object doesn't *have* a time zone. It just represents an instant in time. `Date.toString()` shows that instant in the system local time zone.

Comment: I've edit the question.

Comment: Not in a useful way, unfortunately. We have no idea how you're passing the date to the server, but we *can* see you logging the result of calling `Date.toString()` - see my previous comment. Note that your code using `Calendar` isn't doing anything useful though - you've effectively got `Date d = new Date(timeMillisecond);`.

Comment: I use retrofit to send it to django rest framework

Comment: I know nothing of either of those things, but fundamentally if you're calling `toString()` on the `Date` object and that's part of how you communicate with the server, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Stefano Plese use this: Date date = new Date(); date.getTime();

Answer (score 0):

You can use sdf, set its timezone and parse it accordingly.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));

try {
                            Date dt = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance()));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it will provide you the date in UTC.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy dd,MM hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String utcTime = dateFormat.format(new Date(timeMillisecond));
Log.d("TAG", utcTime);
```

It will provide you the date in **yyyy dd,MM hh:mm:ss** format but you can  provide other format according to your need.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to use `hh` unless you also include an am/pm specifier.